# CodeIgniter xmlrpc Did not receive '200 ok'

Tags: codeigniter, client-server, xml-rpc

I'm trying to implement an xmlrpc server/client per the CodeIgniter User Guide. I've taken the code as is and keep getting

> Did not receive a '200 OK' response from remote server.

I'm running PHP 5.2.1 on the server. A quick google search leads to http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/63287/ which does not help. I've also tried modifying my Xmlrpcs.php file under system/libraries without success.

Comment: I would also love for this to be answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what IS CI actually sending back? Setup test using Firebug and CUrL might help.

I use a CI install with "ajax" controller which handles its own AJAX requests.

Comment: how ajax call would solve this problem. still stuck in the problem